# What Makes G1000 NXi Different From G1000?

Tags: flight-instruments, cockpit, glass-cockpit, g1000

The new displays are installed on the brand new Cessna aircraft and upgrade plans are ready.

But what is the difference from the G1000 that was there from the early 2000s? Is the tablet/phone compatibility (Which can be used for charts) what makes it different? I cant find comparisons on the internet.

In short. What makes G1000 NXi better than G1000?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [official Garmin announcement](https://www.garmin.com/en-US/blog/aviation/announcement-garmin-introduces-g1000-nxi-next-generation-integrated-flight-deck/) lists all new features.

The new hardware features are:

- faster processors resulting in faster start-up, map rendering, etc.
- more modern animations
- a new design with better readability
- LED back-lighting (increased display brightness, clarity and better dimming)
- lower power consumption

The new software features are:

- wireless connectivity (database updates, flight plan transfer and information shared with a mobile device running the Garmin Pilot or ForeFlight apps)
- flight path for visual approaches (both for visualization and auto-pilot)
- full map overlay on the HSI on the PFD
- SurfaceWatch (similar to a [RAAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runway_Awareness_and_Advisory_System))
- full ADS-B compatibility

Further features listed are:

> - Advanced Doppler weather radar capabilities, including ground clutter suppression and turbulence detection as options.
> - COMM frequency identification displays the station ID, as well as frequency type.
> - Display of sectional charts, as well as IFR low/high enroute charts on the MFD.
> - NEXRAD weather radar imagery can be overlaid on the moving map and animated on the MFD, as well as the HSI map.
> - Vertical Situation Display (VSD) incorporates terrain profile view on the MFD, taking into consideration the active flight plan, altitude constraints and winds aloft.
> - Pilots can preview departure and arrival procedures on the MFD prior to loading and activating the procedures.
> - Pilots can optionally overlay European Visual Reporting Points (VRPs) on the moving map, as VRPs are standard within the navigation database.
> - Three-color terrain shading incorporates green, yellow and red contouring, which depicts the aircraft is 2,000, 1,000 and 100 feet above ground level (AGL) respectively.
> - Aircraft maintenance personnel experience faster system software upgrades and streamlined equipment replacement.